# add legend to pyplot, when using single plot call

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I'm used to this syntax when plotting multiple lines:

```
plt.plot(freqs,ps,freqs,psf)
```

I tried different variations of `label=["ps","psf"]` in it, using different kind of parentheses, but I was always unable to obtain a correct legend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.plot` will return a list of handles for the lines. You can pass those to `legend`, along with a list of labels:

```
handles=plt.plot([0,1],[5,6],[0,1],[8,7])
plt.legend(handles,["label a","label b"])
```